# Increase site load time while loading data in static website

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a table containing sponsors data in a section of my static website. Currently I have kept the data in a json file and creating the table using javascript while the website is loading, the js file is included at the end of the html page. So the pseudo code of the page is somthing like

```
<body>
    ...
    <section id="sponsors"></section>
    ...
    <script src="sponsors.js"></script>
</body>
```

The `sponsors.js` loads the data from `sponsors.json` using a `$.get()` and then uses the data to create a table.

My question is which of the following approach increases the site load time?

1. Using the above approach keeping the data in a separate json file.
2. Keeping the data in `sponsors.js` instead of keeping in a separate json file
3. Hard coding the table with the individual data
4. Any other approach not listed above?

Comment: You may have already considered this, but this sounds like a job for a static site generator like Jekyll or Hugo

Comment: Yeah using a static website generator would be the best choice here but I already built a lot of stuff and doing a rewrite will take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 is the fastest approach because the data does not need to be rendered, however hard coding is not very useful.

2 is slightly faster as a seperate request does not need to be made.

1 is the slowest, however if you cached the json in a cookie it would not have to be downloaded every time.  By using an expire on the cookie it would trigger it to be downloaded again.

Comment: Thanks. I should have considered caching. I will look into ways to cache the json data on first load so that the next time the website loads it will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best approach in terms of performance is always the one that involves as few files as possible.

Inlining your JSON would certainly be best for performance, but then you're making a sacrifice in code readability and modularity. You're going to have to make a judgement for yourself on what the best solution is, by balancing ease of programming with performance.

Personally, I'd stick with what you got, because changing the JSON later won't be complicated at all - and the performance hit you'll take won't likely be noticeable, much less game breaking.

Comment: Yes I too like the way it is now. I am considering caching the data on first load so that it loads faster eventually

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the data in an external JSON would increase the time to load the table, but would descrease the time needed to load the page itself.
Instead hard coding the table will load the table instantly but it will also increase the time to load the page.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I notice the behavior after watching the website load a bit closely.